# PHP Content Files inside folder return error 403

Tags: php, permissions, mkdir

Every time a new user registers, it create a folder with the name of the user, this folder has more folder inside: first for Images and the second for videos.
I want to allow user to watch the videos of other users, but when I include the video, it shows ERROR 403, at the start I had mkdir with 755 I changed it to 777 but still getting ERROR 403. This is the function:

```
function createFolder($name){
    if (!is_dir($name)){
        if (mkdir('Src/Usuarios/'.$name,777,true)){
            if (mkdir('Src/Usuarios/'.$name.'/img',777)){
                if (mkdir('Src/Usuarios/'.$name.'/videos',777)){
                    return true;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I don't want to allow user to access to the folder of any user, even their own folder. Just can watch videos or images

If you want, you can take a look to whole code but on Branch->Test, not master:
[GitHub](https://github.com/thewasta/gestorVideo)

Comment: have you checked permission of folder where you are creating subfolders. i.e the parent folder of Src folder should have permission of executable

Comment: I created the folder (right click->new folder) I think it have all permission, but how can I check it?

Comment: on linux/ubuntu you can check properties of folder will show permission in tab.. or try to do ls -al in cmd after going into that directory

Comment: I´m using windows so I used "Get-Acl" n powershell, it says I have FullControl.

Answer (score 0):

try this , i hope this can help you .

```
var_dump(createFolder('test'));
function createFolder($name){
if (!is_dir($name)){
    if (mkdir('Src/Usuarios/'.$name,0777,true)){
        if (mkdir('Src/Usuarios/'.$name.'/img',0777)){
            if (mkdir('Src/Usuarios/'.$name.'/videos',0777)){
                return true;

            }else{
                $error = error_get_last();
                return $error['message'];
            }
        }else{
            $error = error_get_last();
            return $error['message'];
        }
    }else{ 
        $error = error_get_last();
        return $error['message'];
    }
}else{
    return 'not a directory';
}
}

die;
```

just make sure you have permission to your directory where you have kept this function file php page

Comment: This return an error in case mkdir doesn't work. But It does, because it create the folders and when the user upload a video, the video is save inside the folder.

Comment: what is error  you got .. it is just for your reference you can omit the line of error return if you want